# Matching None and absent values with the Rust implementation of Project Fluent

Tags: rust, internationalization, project-fluent

I am working on a fairly complex (for me, anyway) string interpolation using the Rust version of Fluent.

First, the technologies involved:

https://projectfluent.org/

https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent-rs/ (version 0.11.0)

This translation has four parameters to it: Activity, Distance, Duration, and unit system. I'm wanting to output somewhat differently formatted strings based on which of those four is actually present. So, for instance...

```
⁨⁨25⁩ miles⁩ of ⁨biking⁩ in ⁨52⁩ minutes
52⁩ minutes of ⁨biking⁩
⁨⁨25⁩ miles⁩ of ⁨biking⁩
```

And so forth. All of this actually works as I expect in [this Fluent playground snippet](https://projectfluent.org/play/?id=c700c4a01feede347c28535eae36ae7f). You can go to that snippet and change the especially the distance and duration variables to see how I expect the format to change.

However, when I go to the Rust code (copy and paste the message DSL into my translation file), the results I get are quite different:

```
{"distance": String("10.00"), "duration": String("52:00"), "units": String("USA"), "activity": String("Cycling")}
biking

{"units": String("USA"), "distance": String("10.00"), "activity": String("Cycling")}
biking

{"distance": String("10.00"), "activity": String("Cycling"), "units": String("SI")}
biking

{"activity": String("Walking"), "duration": String("52:00")}
walking

{"activity": String("Cycling")}
biking
```

Basically, every interpolation is defaulting to whatever the default branch is, and is not actually pattern matching at all.

Am I mis-understanding the project fluent pattern matches, or have I potentially run into a bug flaw in the Rust implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I had thought this was a bug, and so I [filed it](https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent-rs/issues/168) against the fluent-rs project. It turns out it is not a bug in the project, it is a bug in how I am injecting the data. And a misuse of the pattern matching.

The response from the author has a lot of good information.